# storage of password in django and rainbow tables

Tags: django, passwords, salt, django-authentication

In the `django` docs,it says django creates password as a string `algo$hash`

where algo is `pbkdf2` by default and hash is the `sha256` hash of the  password string .

In some [articles](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm), I read that a secure password is created using a random `salt` which is then stored in the database for each user.This makes it difficult for a malicious user who tries to break the password using `rainbow table`s.But when I checked the auth_user table for my django project ,I could only find a single string which begins `'pbkdf2_sha256$'` for each user.I couldn't find any salt stored.

Does this mean the password stored is vulnerable to attack using raibow table?

Comment: What's your "single string" looks like? I got something like `'pbkdf2_sha256$10000$GDDpkxbrqR4j$DnpLSj4P91ylVfYvtWFs69cdhJiSnLP1G1rw9m4CLCY='`, which does contain a salt part `"GDDpkxbrqR4j"`, by default `pbkdf2_sha256` algo.

Comment: ok,mine also starts with pbkdf2_sha256$ ,but why is the salt not stored in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django documentation explicitly stated that it hashes passwords with a salt [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#passwords) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords):

> The password attribute of a User object is a string in this format:
>
> hashtype$salt$hash
>
> That’s hashtype, salt and hash, separated by the dollar-sign
>   character.
>
> Hashtype is either sha1 (default), md5 or crypt – the algorithm used
>   to perform a one-way hash of the password. Salt is a random string
>   used to salt the raw password to create the hash. Note that the crypt
>   method is only supported on platforms that have the standard Python
>   crypt module available.

so there will be 2 dollar signs, and in between is the salt.